# Drawing polygon: limits?

Tags: r, graphics

The `polygon` function in R seems rather simple...however I can't get it to work.

It easily works with this code:

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- 0.5*dnorm(x,0,1)
plot(x,y1,type="l",bty="L",xlab="X",ylab="dnorm(X)")
points(x,y2,type="l",col="red")
polygon(c(x,rev(x)),c(y2,rev(y1)),col="skyblue")
```

When adopting this to something else, it doesn't work. Here some stuff to reproduce the issue:

```
lowerbound = c(0.05522914,0.06567045,0.07429926,0.08108482,0.08624472,0.09008050,0.09288837,0.09492226)
upperbound = c(0.1743657,0.1494058,0.1333106,0.1227383,0.1156714,0.1108787,0.1075915,0.1053178)
lim = c(100,200,400,800,1600,3200,6400,12800)

plot(upperbound, ylim=c(0, 0.2), type="b", axes=FALSE)
lines(lowerbound, type="b", col="red")
atvalues <- seq(1:8)
axis(side=1, at=atvalues, labels=lim)
axis(side=2, at=c(0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2), labels=c(0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2))
polygon(lowerbound,upperbound, col="skyblue")
```

It also doesn't work when only segmenting a subset when directly calling the coordinates:

```
xpoly <- c(100,200,200,100)
ypoly <- c(lowerbound[1], lowerbound[2], upperbound[2], upperbound[1])
polygon(xpoly,ypoly, col="skyblue")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You'll need `x` and `y` values! `polygon(x = c(seq_along(upperbound), rev(seq_along(lowerbound))), y = c(lowerbound, rev(upperbound)), col="skyblue")` should work..

Comment: `seq_along` is my friend, indeed! And if I only want a section colored between e.g. 100 and 200 along the x-axis? How would you set the boundaries?

Comment: Alright, see the extended answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plotting the whole polygon

You need to supply both `x` and `y` to `polygon`. Normally, you'd also do that for `plot`, but if you don't it will just use the Index as `x`, that is integers 1 to n. We can use that to make an `x` range. `seq_along` will create a 1:n vector, where n is the `length` of another object.

```
x <- c(seq_along(upperbound), rev(seq_along(lowerbound)))
y <- c(lowerbound, rev(upperbound))

plot(upperbound, ylim=c(0, 0.2), type="b", axes=FALSE)
lines(lowerbound, type="b", col="red")
atvalues <- seq(1:8)
axis(side=1, at=atvalues, labels=lim)
axis(side=2, at=c(0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2), labels=c(0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2))
polygon(x = x, y = y, col="skyblue")
```

[image]

### Plotting a subset

For a subset, I would create the `y` first, and then use the old `x` to easily get `x values:

```
y2 <- c(lowerbound[1:2], upperbound[2:1])
x2 <- x[which(y2 == y)]
polygon(x2, y2, col="skyblue")
```

[image]

### How I would do it

Creating something like this is much easier in `ggplot2`, where `geom_ribbon` does a lot of the heavy lifting. We just have to make an actual `data.frame`, an stop relying on indices.

Full polygon:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, ymin = low, ymax = up)) +
  geom_ribbon(fill = 'skyblue', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = low), col = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = up), col = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Subset:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, ymin = low, ymax = up)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = d[1:2, ], fill = 'skyblue', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = low), col = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = up), col = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]